# 'Student_excel$' is not a valid name

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import-from-excel

```
    private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
        openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xlsx";
        openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xlsm";
        txtfilepath.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
    }
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = txtfilepath.Text;

        string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        DataTable Data = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Student_excel$]", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);

            conn.Close();
        }
        string ConnStr = MyConString;
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnStr))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Student_excel";
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("userid", "userid");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("age", "age");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("location", "location");
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Data);
            MessageBox.Show("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
    }
```

When I import some Excel file (ExcelBook1.xlsx) into the windowsFormApplication, Visual Studio give me some error:

> 'Student_excel$' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Comment: Make sure there is a worksheet named "Student_excel" in your excel file.

Comment: @diiN_thx!I find out the reason.

Comment: Hey @Fabre, can you remember the reason?